# Windows search stopped working

Tags: windows, start-menu, windows-search

I'm using Windows 10 Anniversary Update and recently the Windows search feature has stopped working. I think it was due to some copying / cutting around some of the file in my AppData or something (not completely sure about the cause, just guessing)

Here is the result when I try to search for Control panel:

[image: screenshot of Windows search returning no results]

I have tried every single thing I can find on the Web, including restarting Cortana/Windows search service, rebuilding search index ... but nothing could help. Any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: Workaround: use a third-party tool such as DocFetcher (which can index some document types that Windows Search can't).

Comment: I indeed tried to use "Everything" and somehow for searching files it's even better than Windows search. But I'd still prefer if Windows search is restored.

Comment: Use the command to re-register Cortana.

1. Open Windows PowerShell，run as Administrator.

2. Type Get-AppXPackage -Name Microsoft.Windows.Cortana | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}

3. Click Enter.

Comment: Still doesn't work ...

Answer (score 0):

After a rather long time, I decided to fix it in the brute-force way (and it works !) by creating a new user account, copying some important apps config over, then starting everything anew there.

Seems silly, but it works ...